# How to enable another Intel Xeon Phi coprocessor?

Tags: xeon

I have a server with one MIC card (mic0), and it works well. Recently, I added another MIC (mic1) on the same server. mic1 could be detected by `lspci`, but doesn't appear using `ifconfig`. How could I enable mic1 to make it work together with mic0?

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded in enabling the second MIC card on the same server by several commands from http://registrationcenter.intel.com/irc_nas/5079/readme.txt. The keys are two steps in "2.2 Steps to Install Intel(R) MPSS":

```
micctrl --initdefaults
```

and "2.4 Intel(R) Xeon Phi(TM) Coprocessor Flash & SMC Update"

```
/usr/bin/micflash -update -device all -smcbootloader
```

I didn't need to install a separate MPSS module for the mic1 card as I considered before.